# Using wireframe graphs in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the wireframe function in R to plot a surface showing how one variable changes in response to two other variables changing. 
Namely I have output from the optim function in a 3x355 matrix, with three columns headed "r" "k" and "sigma." I'd like to produce a wireframe graph showing how sigma changes with r and k.
But I'm running into trouble with using the wireframe command, as it keeps producing an empty box with nothing in it.

The code I am trying to use looks like: (for the "logs" matrix)

```
logsgrid<-expand.grid(logs[,"sigma"]=logs[,"sigma],logs[,"r"],logs[,"k"])

wireframe(logs["sigma"]~logs["r"]*logs["k"],data=logsgrid)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

My data looks like:

```
> logs
                 r         k       sigma
  [1,]   0.3911590 254.49893   0.5159761
  [2,]   0.3911162 254.50250   0.5159893
  [3,]   0.3910748 254.54044   0.5159333
  [4,]   0.3910345 254.55662   0.5159562
  [5,]   0.3911328 254.48039   0.5160731
  [6,]   0.3910237 254.53855   0.5162077
  [7,]   0.3912773 254.50953   0.5161592
  [8,]   0.3909318 254.64676   0.5164667
  [9,]   0.3865343 258.65899   0.5215749
 [10,]   0.3902477 255.63565   0.5141283
 [11,]   1.8565417  12.88117   4.0498523
 [12,]  -0.2392318  16.68176   4.6337449
 [13,]  -0.4814815  15.55185  20.8000000
 [14,]  -2.2814815  18.25185  22.4000000
 [15,]  -2.4444444  19.55556  24.0000000
 [16,]  -2.6074074  20.85926  25.6000000
 [17,]  -2.7703704  22.16296  27.2000000
 [18,]  -2.9333333  23.46667  28.8000000
 [19,]  -3.0962963  24.77037  30.4000000
 [20,]  -3.2592593  26.07407  32.0000000
 [21,]  -3.4222222  27.37778  33.6000000
 [22,]  -3.5851852  28.68148  35.2000000
 [23,]  -3.7481481  29.98519  36.8000000
 [24,]  -3.9111111  31.28889  38.4000000
 [25,]  -4.0740741  32.59259  40.0000000
 [26,]  -4.2370370  33.89630  41.6000000
 [27,]   2.4000000  32.10000  44.1000000
 [28,]   2.4888889  33.28889  45.7333333
 [29,]   2.5777778  34.47778  47.3666667
 [30,]   2.6666667  35.66667  49.0000000
 [31,]   2.7555556  36.85556  50.6333333
 [32,]   2.8444444  38.04444  52.2666667
 [33,]   2.9333333  39.23333  53.9000000
 [34,]   3.0222222  40.42222  55.5333333
 [35,]   3.1111111  41.61111  57.1666667
 [36,]   3.2000000  42.80000  58.8000000
 [37,]   3.2888889  43.98889  60.4333333
 [38,]   3.3777778  45.17778  62.0666667
 [39,]   3.4666667  46.36667  63.7000000
 [40,]   3.5555556  47.55556  65.3333333
 [41,]   3.6444444  48.74444  66.9666667
 [42,] -11.2000000  51.80000  79.8000000
 [43,] -11.4666667  53.03333  81.7000000
 [44,] -11.7333333  54.26667  83.6000000
 [45,] -12.0000000  55.50000  85.5000000
 [46,]  15.3333333  52.13333  62.8666667
 [47,]  15.6666667  53.26667  64.2333333
 [48,]  16.0000000  54.40000  65.6000000
 [49,]  16.3333333  55.53333  66.9666667
 [50,]  16.6666667  56.66667  68.3333333
 [51,]  17.0000000  57.80000  69.7000000
 [52,]  17.3333333  58.93333  71.0666667
 [53,]  17.6666667  60.06667  72.4333333
 [54,]  18.0000000  61.20000  73.8000000
 [55,]  18.3333333  62.33333  75.1666667
 [56,]  18.6666667  63.46667  76.5333333
 [57,]  19.0000000  64.60000  77.9000000
 [58,]  19.3333333  65.73333  79.2666667
 [59,]  19.6666667  66.86667  80.6333333
 [60,]  20.0000000  68.00000  82.0000000
 [61,]  20.3333333  69.13333  83.3666667
 [62,]  20.6666667  70.26667  84.7333333
 [63,]  21.0000000  71.40000  86.1000000
 [64,]  21.3333333  72.53333  87.4666667
 [65,]  21.6666667  73.66667  88.8333333
 [66,]  22.0000000  74.80000  90.2000000
 [67,]  22.3333333  75.93333  91.5666667
 [68,]  22.6666667  77.06667  92.9333333
 [69,]  23.0000000  78.20000  94.3000000
 [70,]  23.3333333  79.33333  95.6666667
 [71,]  23.6666667  80.46667  97.0333333
 [72,]  24.0000000  81.60000  98.4000000
 [73,]  24.3333333  82.73333  99.7666667
 [74,]  24.6666667  83.86667 101.1333333
 [75,]  25.0000000  85.00000 102.5000000
 [76,]  25.3333333  86.13333 103.8666667
 [77,]  25.6666667  87.26667 105.2333333
 [78,]  26.0000000  88.40000 106.6000000
 [79,]  26.3333333  89.53333 107.9666667
 [80,]  26.6666667  90.66667 109.3333333
 [81,]  27.0000000  91.80000 110.7000000
 [82,]  27.3333333  92.93333 112.0666667
 [83,]  27.6666667  94.06667 113.4333333
 [84,]  28.0000000  95.20000 114.8000000
 [85,]  28.3333333  96.33333 116.1666667
 [86,]  28.6666667  97.46667 117.5333333
 [87,]  29.0000000  98.60000 118.9000000
 [88,]  29.3333333  99.73333 120.2666667
 [89,]  29.6666667 100.86667 121.6333333
 [90,]  30.0000000 102.00000 123.0000000
 [91,]  30.3333333 103.13333 124.3666667
 [92,]  30.6666667 104.26667 125.7333333
 [93,]  31.0000000 105.40000 127.1000000
 [94,]  31.3333333 106.53333 128.4666667
 [95,]  31.6666667 107.66667 129.8333333
 [96,]  32.0000000 108.80000 131.2000000
 [97,]  32.3333333 109.93333 132.5666667
 [98,]  32.6666667 111.06667 133.9333333
 [99,]  33.0000000 112.20000 135.3000000
[100,]  33.3333333 113.33333 136.6666667
[101,]  33.6666667 114.46667 138.0333333
[102,]  34.0000000 115.60000 139.4000000
[103,]  34.3333333 116.73333 140.7666667
[104,]  34.6666667 117.86667 142.1333333
[105,]  35.0000000 119.00000 143.5000000
[106,]  35.3333333 120.13333 144.8666667
[107,]  35.6666667 121.26667 146.2333333
[108,]  36.0000000 122.40000 147.6000000
[109,]  36.3333333 123.53333 148.9666667
[110,]  36.6666667 124.66667 150.3333333
[111,]  37.0000000 125.80000 151.7000000
[112,]  37.3333333 126.93333 153.0666667
[113,]  37.6666667 128.06667 154.4333333
[114,]  38.0000000 129.20000 155.8000000
[115,]  38.3333333 130.33333 157.1666667
[116,]  38.6666667 131.46667 158.5333333
[117,]  39.0000000 132.60000 159.9000000
[118,]  39.3333333 133.73333 161.2666667
[119,]  39.6666667 134.86667 162.6333333
[120,]  40.0000000 136.00000 164.0000000
[121,]  40.3333333 137.13333 165.3666667
[122,]  40.6666667 138.26667 166.7333333
[123,]  41.0000000 139.40000 168.1000000
[124,]  41.3333333 140.53333 169.4666667
[125,]  41.6666667 141.66667 170.8333333
[126,]  42.0000000 142.80000 172.2000000
[127,]  42.3333333 143.93333 173.5666667
[128,]  42.6666667 145.06667 174.9333333
[129,]  43.0000000 146.20000 176.3000000
[130,]  43.3333333 147.33333 177.6666667
[131,]  43.6666667 148.46667 179.0333333
[132,]  44.0000000 149.60000 180.4000000
[133,]  44.3333333 150.73333 181.7666667
[134,]  44.6666667 151.86667 183.1333333
[135,]  45.0000000 153.00000 184.5000000
[136,]  45.3333333 154.13333 185.8666667
[137,]  45.6666667 155.26667 187.2333333
[138,]  46.0000000 156.40000 188.6000000
[139,]  46.3333333 157.53333 189.9666667
[140,]  46.6666667 158.66667 191.3333333
[141,]  47.0000000 159.80000 192.7000000
[142,]  47.3333333 160.93333 194.0666667
[143,]  47.6666667 162.06667 195.4333333
[144,]  48.0000000 163.20000 196.8000000
[145,]  48.3333333 164.33333 198.1666667
[146,]  48.6666667 165.46667 199.5333333
[147,]  49.0000000 166.60000 200.9000000
[148,]  49.3333333 167.73333 202.2666667
[149,]  49.6666667 168.86667 203.6333333
[150,]  50.0000000 170.00000 205.0000000
[151,]  50.3333333 171.13333 206.3666667
[152,]  50.6666667 172.26667 207.7333333
[153,]  51.0000000 173.40000 209.1000000
[154,]  51.3333333 174.53333 210.4666667
[155,]  51.6666667 175.66667 211.8333333
[156,]  52.0000000 176.80000 213.2000000
[157,]  52.3333333 177.93333 214.5666667
[158,]  52.6666667 179.06667 215.9333333
[159,]  53.0000000 180.20000 217.3000000
[160,]  53.3333333 181.33333 218.6666667
[161,]  53.6666667 182.46667 220.0333333
[162,]  54.0000000 183.60000 221.4000000
[163,]  54.3333333 184.73333 222.7666667
[164,]  54.6666667 185.86667 224.1333333
[165,]  55.0000000 187.00000 225.5000000
[166,]  55.3333333 188.13333 226.8666667
[167,]  55.6666667 189.26667 228.2333333
[168,]  56.0000000 190.40000 229.6000000
[169,]  56.3333333 191.53333 230.9666667
[170,]  56.6666667 192.66667 232.3333333
[171,]  57.0000000 193.80000 233.7000000
[172,]  57.3333333 194.93333 235.0666667
[173,]  57.6666667 196.06667 236.4333333
[174,]  58.0000000 197.20000 237.8000000
[175,]  58.3333333 198.33333 239.1666667
[176,]  58.6666667 199.46667 240.5333333
[177,]  59.0000000 200.60000 241.9000000
[178,]  59.3333333 201.73333 243.2666667
[179,]  59.6666667 202.86667 244.6333333
[180,]  60.0000000 204.00000 246.0000000
[181,]  60.3333333 205.13333 247.3666667
[182,]  60.6666667 206.26667 248.7333333
[183,]  61.0000000 207.40000 250.1000000
[184,]  61.3333333 208.53333 251.4666667
[185,]  61.6666667 209.66667 252.8333333
[186,]  62.0000000 210.80000 254.2000000
[187,]  62.3333333 211.93333 255.5666667
[188,]  62.6666667 213.06667 256.9333333
[189,]  63.0000000 214.20000 258.3000000
[190,]  63.3333333 215.33333 259.6666667
[191,]  63.6666667 216.46667 261.0333333
[192,]  64.0000000 217.60000 262.4000000
[193,]  64.3333333 218.73333 263.7666667
[194,]  64.6666667 219.86667 265.1333333
[195,]  65.0000000 221.00000 266.5000000
[196,]  65.3333333 222.13333 267.8666667
[197,]  65.6666667 223.26667 269.2333333
[198,]  66.0000000 224.40000 270.6000000
[199,]  66.3333333 225.53333 271.9666667
[200,]  66.6666667 226.66667 273.3333333
[201,]  67.0000000 227.80000 274.7000000
[202,]  67.3333333 228.93333 276.0666667
[203,]  67.6666667 230.06667 277.4333333
[204,]  68.0000000 231.20000 278.8000000
[205,]  68.3333333 232.33333 280.1666667
[206,]  68.6666667 233.46667 281.5333333
[207,]  69.0000000 234.60000 282.9000000
[208,]  69.3333333 235.73333 284.2666667
[209,]  69.6666667 236.86667 285.6333333
[210,]  70.0000000 238.00000 287.0000000
[211,]  70.3333333 239.13333 288.3666667
[212,]  70.6666667 240.26667 289.7333333
[213,]  71.0000000 241.40000 291.1000000
[214,]  71.3333333 242.53333 292.4666667
[215,]  71.6666667 243.66667 293.8333333
[216,]  72.0000000 244.80000 295.2000000
[217,]  72.3333333 245.93333 296.5666667
[218,]  72.6666667 247.06667 297.9333333
[219,]  73.0000000 248.20000 299.3000000
[220,]  73.3333333 249.33333 300.6666667
[221,]  73.6666667 250.46667 302.0333333
[222,]  74.0000000 251.60000 303.4000000
[223,]  74.3333333 252.73333 304.7666667
[224,]  74.6666667 253.86667 306.1333333
[225,]  75.0000000 255.00000 307.5000000
[226,]  75.3333333 256.13333 308.8666667
[227,]  75.6666667 257.26667 310.2333333
[228,]  76.0000000 258.40000 311.6000000
[229,]  76.3333333 259.53333 312.9666667
[230,]  76.6666667 260.66667 314.3333333
[231,]  77.0000000 261.80000 315.7000000
[232,]  77.3333333 262.93333 317.0666667
[233,]  77.6666667 264.06667 318.4333333
[234,]  78.0000000 265.20000 319.8000000
[235,]  78.3333333 266.33333 321.1666667
[236,]  78.6666667 267.46667 322.5333333
[237,]  79.0000000 268.60000 323.9000000
[238,]  79.3333333 269.73333 325.2666667
[239,]  79.6666667 270.86667 326.6333333
[240,]  80.0000000 272.00000 328.0000000
[241,]  80.3333333 273.13333 329.3666667
[242,]  80.6666667 274.26667 330.7333333
[243,]  81.0000000 275.40000 332.1000000
[244,]  81.3333333 276.53333 333.4666667
[245,]  81.6666667 277.66667 334.8333333
[246,]  82.0000000 278.80000 336.2000000
[247,]  82.3333333 279.93333 337.5666667
[248,]  82.6666667 281.06667 338.9333333
[249,]  83.0000000 282.20000 340.3000000
[250,]  83.3333333 283.33333 341.6666667
[251,]  83.6666667 284.46667 343.0333333
[252,]  84.0000000 285.60000 344.4000000
[253,]  84.3333333 286.73333 345.7666667
[254,]  84.6666667 287.86667 347.1333333
[255,]  85.0000000 289.00000 348.5000000
[256,]  85.3333333 290.13333 349.8666667
[257,]  85.6666667 291.26667 351.2333333
[258,]  86.0000000 292.40000 352.6000000
[259,]  86.3333333 293.53333 353.9666667
[260,]  86.6666667 294.66667 355.3333333
[261,]  87.0000000 295.80000 356.7000000
[262,]  87.3333333 296.93333 358.0666667
[263,]  87.6666667 298.06667 359.4333333
[264,]  88.0000000 299.20000 360.8000000
[265,]  88.3333333 300.33333 362.1666667
[266,]  88.6666667 301.46667 363.5333333
[267,]  89.0000000 302.60000 364.9000000
[268,]  89.3333333 303.73333 366.2666667
[269,]  89.6666667 304.86667 367.6333333
[270,]  90.0000000 306.00000 369.0000000
[271,]  90.3333333 307.13333 370.3666667
[272,]  90.6666667 308.26667 371.7333333
[273,]  91.0000000 309.40000 373.1000000
[274,]  91.3333333 310.53333 374.4666667
[275,]  91.6666667 311.66667 375.8333333
[276,]  92.0000000 312.80000 377.2000000
[277,]  92.3333333 313.93333 378.5666667
[278,]  92.6666667 315.06667 379.9333333
[279,]  93.0000000 316.20000 381.3000000
[280,]  93.3333333 317.33333 382.6666667
[281,]  93.6666667 318.46667 384.0333333
[282,]  94.0000000 319.60000 385.4000000
[283,]  94.3333333 320.73333 386.7666667
[284,]  94.6666667 321.86667 388.1333333
[285,]  95.0000000 323.00000 389.5000000
[286,]  95.3333333 324.13333 390.8666667
[287,]  95.6666667 325.26667 392.2333333
[288,]  96.0000000 326.40000 393.6000000
[289,]  96.3333333 327.53333 394.9666667
[290,]  96.6666667 328.66667 396.3333333
[291,]  97.0000000 329.80000 397.7000000
[292,]  97.3333333 330.93333 399.0666667
[293,]  97.6666667 332.06667 400.4333333
[294,]  98.0000000 333.20000 401.8000000
[295,]  98.3333333 334.33333 403.1666667
[296,]  98.6666667 335.46667 404.5333333
[297,]  99.0000000 336.60000 405.9000000
[298,]  99.3333333 337.73333 407.2666667
[299,]  99.6666667 338.86667 408.6333333
[300,] 100.0000000 340.00000 410.0000000
[301,] 100.3333333 341.13333 411.3666667
[302,] 100.6666667 342.26667 412.7333333
[303,] 101.0000000 343.40000 414.1000000
[304,] 101.3333333 344.53333 415.4666667
[305,] 101.6666667 345.66667 416.8333333
[306,] 102.0000000 346.80000 418.2000000
[307,] 102.3333333 347.93333 419.5666667
[308,] 102.6666667 349.06667 420.9333333
[309,] 103.0000000 350.20000 422.3000000
[310,] 103.3333333 351.33333 423.6666667
[311,] 103.6666667 352.46667 425.0333333
[312,] 104.0000000 353.60000 426.4000000
[313,] 104.3333333 354.73333 427.7666667
[314,] 104.6666667 355.86667 429.1333333
[315,] 105.0000000 357.00000 430.5000000
[316,] 105.3333333 358.13333 431.8666667
[317,] 105.6666667 359.26667 433.2333333
[318,] 106.0000000 360.40000 434.6000000
[319,] 106.3333333 361.53333 435.9666667
[320,] 106.6666667 362.66667 437.3333333
[321,] 107.0000000 363.80000 438.7000000
[322,] 107.3333333 364.93333 440.0666667
[323,] 107.6666667 366.06667 441.4333333
[324,] 108.0000000 367.20000 442.8000000
[325,] 108.3333333 368.33333 444.1666667
[326,] 358.6000000 326.00000 326.0000000
[327,] 359.7000000 327.00000 327.0000000
[328,] 360.8000000 328.00000 328.0000000
[329,] 361.9000000 329.00000 329.0000000
[330,] 363.0000000 330.00000 330.0000000
[331,] 364.1000000 331.00000 331.0000000
[332,] 365.2000000 332.00000 332.0000000
[333,] 366.3000000 333.00000 333.0000000
[334,] 367.4000000 334.00000 334.0000000
[335,] 368.5000000 335.00000 335.0000000
[336,] 369.6000000 336.00000 336.0000000
[337,] 370.7000000 337.00000 337.0000000
[338,] 371.8000000 338.00000 338.0000000
[339,] 372.9000000 339.00000 339.0000000
[340,] 374.0000000 340.00000 340.0000000
[341,] 375.1000000 341.00000 341.0000000
[342,] 376.2000000 342.00000 342.0000000
[343,] 377.3000000 343.00000 343.0000000
[344,] 378.4000000 344.00000 344.0000000
[345,] 379.5000000 345.00000 345.0000000
[346,] 380.6000000 346.00000 346.0000000
[347,] 381.7000000 347.00000 347.0000000
[348,] 382.8000000 348.00000 348.0000000
[349,] 383.9000000 349.00000 349.0000000
[350,] 385.0000000 350.00000 350.0000000
[351,] 386.1000000 351.00000 351.0000000
[352,] 387.2000000 352.00000 352.0000000
[353,] 388.3000000 353.00000 353.0000000
[354,] 389.4000000 354.00000 354.0000000
[355,] 390.5000000 355.00000 355.0000000
[356,] 391.6000000 356.00000 356.0000000
[357,] 392.7000000 357.00000 357.0000000
```

Comment: I am guessing `wireframe(sigma ~ r * k, data=as.data.frame(logs))` should work, but it is hard to know without seeing the data.

Comment: I could post the data but its all +ve values. This just produced an empty box as well

Comment: What does "+ve" mean? I think `wireframe` requires all that you have a complete grid across `k` and `r` and won't work in case one combination is missing. Try making a 3-d scatterplot instead that does not require this, *e.g.* with the `rgl` package.

Comment: +ve means positive sorry force of habit. What do you mean by complete grid? I can make a 3d scatterplot using clouds buts for my data set its not very informative

Comment: I mean if `k` can take the values 1:10 and `r` can take the values 1:7, has `sigma` been calculated for all 70 possible combinations of `k` and `r`? Test it with `nrow(logs) == length(unique(logs[,"k"]))*length(unique(logs[,"r"]))`.

Comment: No the data aren't organised like that, its a 355 long matrix where every row corresponds to the values taken by sigma for that r and k. I'll post the data.

Comment: Even this is possible duplicate .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979240/r-plotting-a-3d-surface-from-x-y-z?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if the results make sense or not (that's up to you), but here's a solution with `akima::interp` and `lattice::wireframe`:

```
dat <- read.table("wftmp.dat",header=TRUE)
require("akima")
s <- with(dat,interp(r,k,sigma))
library("lattice")
with(s,wireframe(z,row.values=x,col.values=y))
```

[image]

However, looking at the raw data with `rgl`  and adding the interpolated surface (you could have looked at the raw data with `scatterplot3d` as well) shows that the interpolation doesn't make much sense:

```
library("rgl")
with(dat,plot3d(r,k,sigma,col="red"))
surface3d(s$x,s$y,s$z,col="gray")
```

[image]

That is, your data lie along a couple of lines in the (x,y,z) space, so the interpolation is a bit silly.

You probably could have figured this out with a `pairs` plot from base R as well ...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot plot this kind of data with a `wireframe` plot since `r` and `k` does not form a grid.

What you can do is

```
library(rgl)
plot3d(logs[,"r"], logs[,"k"], logs[,"sigma"], type="s")
```

Comment: Did you look at the question linked by @geektrader: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979240/r-plotting-a-3d-surface-from-x-y-z?lq=1 ?  That uses `rgl`, but the solution by @ spacedman gives a general method (using `akima::interp`) that should also be usable with `wireframe`.

Comment: Installing `rgl` is not as straight forward to install as normal packages since it requires openGL and other system specific stuff. It is well worth it tough, it produces very nice graphics. What operating system are you running?