# Creating wireframes from .pts files

Tags: r, point-clouds

I have .pts file data from Landmark that I am trying to create wireframes in R. Unfortunately, the only resources I saw involved MorphoJ. Is there anyways I can create a wire frame from .pts files? Should I convert them to .csv files?

Comment: Welcome to Stakoverflow. The cran `Morpho` pkg provides capability to read Landmark .pts files. It (Morpho) 'suggests' lattice pkg that can also produce wireframes. I would guess that Morpho would provide a more straightforward tool chain/process and lots of good advice in their github. Install all dependencies and give Morpho a try.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15350212/17486894. Just make sure you convert the points readed with {Morpho} package to data frame.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using wireframe graphs in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340658/using-wireframe-graphs-in-r)