# 3D plot of two variables z1 and z2 which are depending on x and y data in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I am pretty new to plotting 3D graphs in R. I can easily work on scatter plot in 2D.

Here I am showing only `Z1` just for the assumption of data. In reality `Z2` also exists.

I have a dataset something like:

```
  X    Y       Z1
 10 8017 5.238290
 13 8273 5.368710
 15 9500 5.908030
 17 6856 6.501010
 19 8453 7.319200
 20 4517 6.258901
 21 7095 5.781290
 24 7738 6.979810
 25 8561 6.563700
 26 7111 6.636700
 29 9596 9.374410
```

How can I plot `A` along the x axis, `B` along the y axis and `Z1` along the z axis? How can I form a bar 3d, mesh 3d and patch 3d ?

I did try on `surface3d` and `plot3d` but got error in handling data.

Please help on this.

The `plot3d` command produces a plot which is of no use. and also `type` is not working inside this command to change the shape (giving a blank plot page).

```
b <- read.table("dataset", header = T)

plot3d(b$X, b$Y, b$Z, xlab="x", ylab="y", zlab="z", col=rainbow(1000))
```

[image]

Instead of scattered points of `Z1` along x and y, I'd like `Z1` to be shown as 3D bars.

And `surface3d` is throwing error like

```
"Error in rgl.surface(x = c(10L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 24L, 25L,  : 
  y length != x rows * z cols"
```

My data is already combined into a dataset and I am accessing separate column into the `surface3d` command but I don't have a clue what else I need to do.

Comment: Never just say "I got an error". You should tell us what your error is.

Comment: can you show us the code you tried and the error you received?

Comment: also, if you want `Z1` and `Z2` both plotted it would be good to present an example that includes both.  Otherwise you're likely to be disappointed (and answerers will be frustrated).

Comment: I will post the results in a minute.

Comment: Check out the `latticeExtra` package. For a single `z` variable it's pretty straightforward to adapt the examples in the docs, e.g., `?panel.3dbars`. For example: `cloud(Z1~X+Y, d, panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, xbase=1, ybase=300, scales=list(arrows=FALSE))` (where `d` is your data.frame).

Comment: `surface3d`requires that `x` and `y` are the row and column numbers of your `z` (or that `z` is a matrix representing the surface). See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4052052/489704) for a way to interpolate your data into regularly-spaced points.

Comment: Yeah I am going through, But your previous hint, works well except I need to beautify it a little. But I will go through surface3d also just to check which one produces better plots and flexibility. Thanks

Comment: A lot of Sarkar's Lattice book is available as a [Google Book](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=gXxKFWkE9h0C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) - worth checking out. But... representing one of your three dimensions with colour (i.e. multiple series of differently coloured lines) might get your message across more simply. Think about whether you even need a 3d plot.