# plotting 3D surface with plotly (matrix transformation with akima::interp)

Tags: r, plotly

In order to plot a surface in plotly with x, y, z, we can use the function `interp` to create the data (as input for the `add_surface` function in plotly)

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405167/r-plotly-how-to-get-3d-surface-with-lat-long-and-z) give the solution.

I follow the different steps.
With the follow code, we can plotly a surface with markers.

```
library(akima)
library(plotly)

x=rep(seq(-1,5,0.2),time=31,each=1)
y=rep(seq(-1,5,0.2),time=1,each=31)

df=data.frame(x=x,y=y,
              z=2*x+y-1.4)


fig <- plot_ly()%>% add_markers(data=df,x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z,
          marker = list(color = "blue",
                        showscale = TRUE))

fig
```

We can see the following plot

[image]

Then I use `interp` to create the data for the surface, and I plot the surface together with the markers.

```
s = interp(x = df$x, y = df$y, z = df$z)

fig <- plot_ly()%>% 
  add_surface(x = s$x, y = s$y, z = s$z)%>%
  add_markers(data=df,x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z,
              marker = list(color = "blue",
                            showscale = TRUE))

fig
```

I have the following image.

[image]

We can see that the result is different. And I can't see why.

When I try to change the function to generate z, sometimes, the two surfaces are the same. For example, for this data.frame

```
df=data.frame(x=x,y=y,
              z=x+y+1)
```

We have the following image. And we can see that this time, we get the same surfaces.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the meanings of `x` and `y` are swapped in the `add_surface` versus the meanings in `interp`.  The example that worked had `x` and `y` appear symmetrically.  So swap them back by transposing the `z` matrix:

```
fig <- plot_ly()%>% 
  add_surface(x = s$x, y = s$y, z = t(s$z))%>%
  add_markers(data=df,x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z,
              marker = list(color = "blue",
                            showscale = TRUE))

fig
```

This is just a guess because the documentation in `plotly` is so weak.  `akima::interp` clearly documents that rows of `z` correspond to different `x` values.