# How to predict gam model with random effect in R?

Tags: r, plotly, predict, gam, random-effects

I am working on predicting `gam` model with random effect to produce 3D surface plot by `plot_ly`.

Here is my code;

```
x <- runif(100)
y <- runif(100)
z <- x^2 + y + rnorm(100)
r <- rep(1,times=100) # random effect
r[51:100] <- 2 # replace 1 into 2, making two groups
df <- data.frame(x, y, z, r)

gam_fit <- gam(z ~ s(x) + s(y) + s(r,bs="re"), data = df) # fit

#create matrix data for `add_surface` function in `plot_ly`
newx <- seq(0, 1, len=20)
newy <- seq(0, 1, len=30)
newxy <- expand.grid(x = newx, y = newy)
z <- matrix(predict(gam_fit, newdata = newxy), 20, 30) # predict data as matrix
```

However, the last line results in error;

```
Error in model.frame.default(ff, data = newdata, na.action = na.act) : 
   variable lengths differ (found for 'r')
In addition: Warning message:
In predict.gam(gam_fit, newdata = newxy) :
  not all required variables have been supplied in  newdata!
```

Thanks to the previous answer, I am sure that above codes work without random effect, as in  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61560264/how-to-return-matrix-of-z-values-along-x-y-coordinates-to-make-3d-surface-plot-b/61592593#61592593).

How can I predict gam models with random effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want the surface conditional upon the random effects (but not for a specific level of the random effect), there are two ways.

The first is to provide a level for the random effect but exclude that term from the predicted values using the `exclude` argument to `predict.gam()`. The second is to again use `exclude` but this time to not provide any data for the random effect and instead stop `predict.gam()` from checking the `newdata` using the argument `newdata.guaranteed = TRUE`.

#### Option 1:

```r
newxy1 <- with(df, expand.grid(x = newx, y = newy, r = 2))
z1 <- predict(gam_fit, newdata = newxy1, exclude = 's(r)')
z1 <- matrix(z1, 20, 30)
```

#### Option 2:

```r
z2 <- predict(gam_fit, newdata = newxy, exclude = 's(r)',
              newdata.guaranteed=TRUE)
z2 <- matrix(z2, 20, 30)
```

These produce the same result:

```
> all.equal(z1, z2)
[1] TRUE
```

A couple of notes:

1. Which you use will depend on how complex the rest of you model is. I would generally use the first option as it provides an extra check against me doing something stupid when creating the data. But in this instance, with a simple model and set of covariates it seems safe enough to trust that `newdata` is OK.
2. Your example uses a random slope (was that intended?), not a random intercept as `r` is not a factor. If your real example uses a factor random effect then you'll need to be a little more careful when creating the `newdata` as you need to get the `levels` of the factor right. For example:

   ```
   expand.grid(x = newx, y = newy,
               r = with(df, factor(2, levels = levels(r))))
   ```

   should get the right set-up for a factor `r`

Comment: Thank you very much!